# Why is my character count incorrect?

Tags: c, linux, text, space, word-count

The following code gets the number of words:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; chars[i] != EOF; i++)
{
    if (chars[i] == ' ')
    {
         count++;
    }
}
```

My problem is, that it doesn't count the words correctly.

For example, if my `file.txt` has the following text in it:

```
spaced-out there's I'd like
```

It says I have `6 words`, when according to *MS Word* I'd have `4`.

```
spaced-out and in
```

Gives me a word count of `4`.

```
spaced out and in
```

Gives me a word count of `6`

I'm sorry if this question has been answered before, Google doesn't take into account the special characters in the search, so it is hard to find the answer to coding. I'd preferably have the words just by identifying if it's a space or not.

I tried looking for answers but no one seemed to have the same problem exactly. I know that the `.txt` files might end in `/r/n` in Windows, but then that should be part of one word. For example:

```
spaced out and in/r/n
```

I believe it should still give me `4` words. Also when I add `|| chars[i] == '\n'` as:

```
for (int i = 0; chars[i] != EOF || chars[i] == '\n'; i++)
```

I get even more words, `8` for the line

```
spaced out and in
```

I am doing this on a Linux-based server, but on an SSH client on Windows. The characters come from a `.txt` file.

---

Edit: Okay, here is the code, I avoided the `#include` when posting it.

```
#define BUF_SIZE 500            
#define OUTPUT_MODE 0700        

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int input, output;
    int readSize = 1, writeSize;            
    char chars[BUF_SIZE];   
    int count = 0;

    input = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);                

    output = creat(argv[2], OUTPUT_MODE);   

    while (readSize > 0)                
    {
        readSize = read(input, chars, BUF_SIZE); 
        if (readSize < 0)       
        exit(4);

        for (int i = 0; chars[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            if (chars[i] == ' ')
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        writeSize = write(output, chars, readSize);     
        if (writeSize <= 0)             
        {
            close(input);       
            close(output);
            printf("%d words\n", count);
            exit(5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that `chars[i] == EOF` at any point. Please post how you populated `chars`.

Comment: `EOF` is not a valid character in a string, in fact you won't find it in a string. `EOF` is value that functions like `fgetc` return for indication of end-of-file.

Comment: Do you have trailing spaces in those lines? If you do, you need to get rid of those.

Comment: @Pablo, you used almost the same words I did in my answer.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi yes I noticed that.

Comment: I have previously done char[i] != '\0', and it was the same outcome I believe I will switch it back to '\0'.

Comment: `char[i] != '\0'` is correct, because `'\0'` marks the end of the string.

Comment: @Lukali Guessing will not solve the problem, it will only "*appear to have solved it*", if you don't find the **REAL** reason for the unexpected outcome, it will happen again.

Comment: @Pablo The thing is, *is `'\0'` really present in the array?*. Something that is impossible to guess from the current question.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi yes, we don't know that, but that doesn't change the fact, that the correct way of checking for the end of the strings is by looking for the `'\0'`-terminating byte, regardless of whether it is in the buffer or not. If it's not in the buffer, then the caller is using the function wrong.

Comment: " it doesn't count the words correctly." --> post the definition of `chars` and a [MCVE]

Comment: My chars are populated like this: chars[BUF_SIZE], where BUF_SIZE is 500 characters. So I count the chars  and then it puts the next batch of 500 from the file. So at the end of the file, some of the array will be empty if last batch is less than 500.

Comment: @Lukali Rather than describe the code, better and clearer to post it -in the question.  Sample input is useful too.

Comment: @chux I have included the code now, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Lukali, The `'\0'` will not be in the file either. Instead try `i < readSize`.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Thanks for that suggestion I have tried that and it did give me a more accurate count. I have one more issue though, the last word in my file is not counted because there is no space after it in the file. there is nothing after that word, so how would I determine if its a word in such case? I tried to use buf[i] == NULL as an alternative case, but it only makes sense for it not to work. I could just add one to word count automatically, but some files might have that extra space. I thought maybe at the end there's /n, but then there is /n after some ' ' too...

Comment: You should check that `readSize > 0` which means that there is at least one word, so you initialize the counter to one, then count the spaces. Note that after counting the first word, if there is a space then there are two words, so after counting the first word, counting spaces is effectively the same as counting words. Please note that things like `'\0'` or `NULL` are set by programmers, and they are not stored in files, nor automatically set by the compiler. When you write `char buffer[10]`; all 10 values of buffer are "*uninitialized*"!!!

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi If there is one word, then I can add one to the word count, but then it would be incorrect for any file which has a word and then a space after it before it ends? It looks like I am just going to have to make a random choice here...

Comment: You should remove superflous spaces too, just think about it and it makes sense. A space not followed by a non-space should not be counted. For example, a space followed by another space, should be ignored. When I said counting spaces I meant counting them correctly.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi okay but if I put 'if (chars[i] == ' ' && buf[i+1] != ' ')', it does indeed count correctly if there is a double gap, but when I changed the file so that there is a space after the last word, or more like the dot after that sentence, my word count was one up even though it should be one less. It would indeed count correctly now if there is nothing after the last dot, but not if there is one space. EDIT: assuming i added one if file wasn't empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am writing this answer because I think, I know what your confusion is. But note that you did not explain how you read the file, I'll give an example and explain why we test `!= EOF`, which is not a character that you read from a file.

It appears that you think `EOF` is a character that is stored in the file, well it's not. If you just want to count words you can do something like

```
int chr;
while ((chr = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    count += (chr == ' ') ? 1 : 0;
```

note that `chr` MUST be of type `int` because `EOF` is of type `int`, but it's certainly not present in the file! It's returned by functions like `fgetc()` to indicate that there is nothing more to read, note that an attempt to read must be made in order for it to return it.

Oops, also note that my sample code will not count the last word. But that's for you to figure out.

Also, this would count multiple spaces as "*words*" something that you should also workout.

Comment: what if I had char[i] != '\0' ? Its just that I have been given the array of those chars already, so I'd like to use that array instead of reading the file to get the chars. I've just checked and I get the same character count when I use '\0'.

Comment: @Lukali If you don't show your code, it's impossible to further help you.

Comment: I've included it now if you've got time to take a look maybe, thank you.